# SSIS, Importing multiple datasets from one CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

I have been given a set of csv files with 2 datasets, neither of which is a fixed length. Can anyone suggest how I could extract the datasets from the file to import them to seperate tables in SQL.

File format is

- 17 lines of header information
- Word "SUMMARY"
- Col headers for section one
- Section one * many rows
- blank line
- Word "DETAIL"
- Col headers for section two
- Section two * many rows

**EDITED**

If anyone wants to experiment, I am assuming the file is like this:

```
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
blah 
SUMMARY
headers1
S1L1
S1L2
S1L3

DETAIL
headers2
S2L1
S2L2
S2L3
```

Comment: Is it possible to split to 2 files before you import the data?

Comment: right now it is, but I need to fully automate the process and then I won't be able to manually split the file. if theres a method in SSIS for splitting files apart, that would work

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit for clarification.

Comment: You could use a script task to do that, as long as you know for sure the structure is same, regardless of number of lines per section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Marks Suggestion, i built this as my first cut Script task. It needs The summary section adding but thats easy enough. (Scripted task Object c#)

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here            
        System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = null;
        string line=null;
        string inputfile = Dts.Variables["SourceFiles"].Value.ToString();
        var infile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputfile);
        string outpath = Dts.Variables["DetailFiles"].Value.ToString();
        int CounterPart = (int)Dts.Variables["CounterPart"].Value;
        outpath = string.Format(outpath, CounterPart++);
        outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outpath);

        while (line != "Detail") {
            line = infile.ReadLine();
                    }

        while (!infile.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = infile.ReadLine();
            outfile.WriteLine(line);
        }

        outfile.Dispose();
        infile.Dispose();

        Dts.Variables["DataFile"].Value=outpath;
        Dts.Variables["CounterPart"].Value = CounterPart;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It will be safe to include !infile.EndOfStream in the first while loop as well - just in case some day you get no Detail section.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do it if you can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{out=""}/SUMMARY/{out="1.csv";next}/DETAIL/{out="2.csv";next}/^$/{out="";next} length(out){print > out}' file
```

At the start it sets the output filename to nothing. Then, if it sees the word "SUMMARY" it sets the output filename to "1.csv". If it sees the word "DETAIL" it sets the output filename to "2.csv". On other lines, it checks to see if the output file is specified, and writes to it if it is.

Your two sections will end up in "1.csv" and "2.csv". The script does not rely on numbers of lines at all, just the words "SUMMARY" and "DETAIL".

Comment: I don't use awk. however this and the comments above have sent me into c# script lands which, with this to guide me, seems to be giving me a viable script.